# How should I tokenize a string and enter the tokens into a list, using whitespace as the delimiter?

Tags: c++, string, tokenize

I have taken many looks, but I have not been able to find a working snippet which I would understand at my current learning level. What I'm aiming to do is again:

- **Take input:**`string input = "Eggs and Spam";`
- **Tokenize it, and then put the tokens (together) into a list:**   Which I see as this: `inputlist = ["Eggs", "and", "Spam"];`

First, I may like to know how to (hopefully briefly) declare a list, and do the above by appending the list.

In terms of C++, I'm also curious how I could do so when using only the default libraries, as I am having trouble handling library files at the moment.

Comment: any specific language you want to do this in?  or are you more generally asking about the abstract procedure that you would need to follow?

Comment: I edited the question to include the specific language, but I would love an explanation on how the vector arrays work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using Boost's Strings Algorithm library - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#idp206847064

Then it's as easy as:

```
vector<string> parts;
split( parts, "Eggs and Spam", is_any_of(" "), token_compress_on )
```

Comment: He explicitly said no 3rd party libraries, though otherwise you're right.

Comment: Now that I see that snippet once again, I can't help but see to setting up the library when I get the time. However, my one concern is this: If I compile a program referring to a non-generic library, would the program be able to work without including the boost library files with it?

Comment: You could compile & link it statically, which would include the 3rd party libraries inside your resulting binary, simplifying distribution.

Comment: Neat! However, when I attempt to **#include** the library, using the path posted on the boost website, the GNU GCC compiler I use always turns out errors. How could I fix that? (In the case this matters, I use the Code::Blocks IDE)

Comment: Without details on the errors I can't help.. Make sure you add the include path to the compile line ( `-I` ) and the library path and name to the link line ( `-Ldirectory -lboost` )